# Fast Real Time Text Transfer Prtocol

Tags: networking, xmpp, real-time

I need to transfer commands between two remote java applications.

I am currently using XMPP to transfer the text of the commands, but it is a bit too slow for rapid sequences of commands.

Are there any protocols which would allow me to achieve near real time text transfer? (for example what protocols are normally used in multiplayer online games) Or is there any way that I would be able to speed up XMPP?

Edit: I'm focusing on getting two apps communicating at the moment. Rapid sequences would be about 10-20 messages (of about 30 characters in length) per second.

Comment: More information would be helpful to understand what constitutes a command, and some numbers for "rapid sequences".  There are also different client libraries and server implementations which will have varying differences in performance.  So how many remote apps are actually communicating at any given point in time can also affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ICE to set up an RTP-connection between the peers. Ice4j is a Java-based library that you could use for this.